# script in shell downloaded by won't execute

Tags: command-line, scripts

I downloaded this file: Renta2015_unix_1_30.sh changed the permission to executable but it won't execute. There seem to be a way to do it in terminal, but it requires the command `cd` and then the location/, but when I try to type `cd desktop/` or `cd downloads/` terminal tells me that:

```
zohar@zohar-M61PME-S2:~$ cd home/
bash: cd: home/: No existe el archivo o el directorio that the file or directory don't exist.
```

Please help?

Comment: `cd /home` instead of `cd home/`

Comment: i think you meant to type, `cd /home/Desktop/` or `cd  /Desktop/`. Notice the capital letter D!!! ubuntu has tab completion to help you out for situations like this, basically you type the little you can remember  and then press TAB for suggestions of what you want, eg `cd` followed by TAB

Comment: Use "cd ~/" to get to your home/ location, or use "cd ~/Desktop" to get to your desktop location, or use "cd ~/Downloads" to get to your downloads location.  Note: file and directory names are case sensitive.  The "~" is kind of a shortcut that points to *your* home folder; other users have their own home folders.  These are all located in "/home" Notice the "/" in *front* of "/home"; this *first* "/" is kind of like the "C:\" on Windows; everything starts from there.  You can see what other user's home folders are on your computer if you type "cd /home" and the type "ls -l" to list the files.

Comment: Thanks you have been most helpful. Just managed to execute. It was especially helpful to use capital letter for the directory after cd. I don't see a place where to say that the question has been answered.

Comment: @PJSingh could you convert your comment to an answer. Then it can be marked as accepted by OP

Comment: hi @Wayne_Yux, i have since put my comment as an answer bellow, seeing that you said that is what helped you. You may go ahead and mark it as the answer if it did indeed answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to type, `cd /home/Desktop/` or `cd /Desktop/`. Notice the capital letter **D**!!! Ubuntu has tab completion to help you out for situations like this, basically you type the little you can remember and then press <kbd>TAB</kbd> for suggestions of what you want, eg `cd` followed by <kbd>TAB</kbd>.